# Two pseudo elements ::before with different properties

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Used two pseudo elements `::before` with different `border` properties (see js fiddle). Despite "you can use only one `::before` and one `::after` pseudo element" this actualy worked. Why?

https://jsfiddle.net/8L7zou3e/1/

`<div class="el"></div>`

```
.el {
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px 0 0 500px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #AA4343;
}
.el:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid #e86d0a;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -50px;
}

.el:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #e86d0a;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -50px;
}
```

Comment: It's like declaring x2 style rules for `.el` they will both apply, and if one style has a style declared that another doesn't, it will get applied as well. Inspect the code and you will notice both style rules applied, the last one in the *cascade* order will over-qualify the rules declared before it, leaving the only rule it doesn't already have, the `border-top` rule.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError 2x?

Comment: @Soolie I'm not good at maths. Can I call a friend?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Call me... :D

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError `√5+75e10*50`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have only one pseudo element.

[image: cons]

And that's here in the UI:

[image: pseudo]

Your CSS cascades to:

```css
.el:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid #e86d0a;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #e86d0a;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  top: 0;
  left: -50px;
}
```

See the way Chrome has treated your combined CSS:

[image: chrome treatment]

Answer (score 3):

There's only one pseudo-element but the properties are added because the two rules apply to that pseudo-element.

Your CSS is equivalent to

```
.el {
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px 0 0 500px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #AA4343;
}
.el:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid #e86d0a;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #e86d0a;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    top: 0;
    left: -50px;
}
```

It's similar to this case which probably is more obvious:

```
a {
   color: red;
}
a {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```